# Tuleap git plugin

Tags: centos, git, tuleap

I just installed Tuleap version 8.7.99.12. on CentOS 6.7. My git version on CentOS is 1.7.12.4.
In Tuleap Admin panel I installed Git Plugin 4.89 and enabled it! In my project admin section I choose Service Configuration to manage existing services. But git is not available! Do I have to define the service by myself? Cannot find any info on that or any parameters for config. The service git is not listed anywhere! So git is not available! Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 0):

Do you see the following elements in the administration page:

- the GIT service in the "configuration of predefined services" link ("Configuration ->  Project configuration:" fieldset): when clicking on this link, check that the service is available; if not maybe that is why you do not see it in a new project)
- the "Git Plugin" link ("Plugins" fieldset)
- the Git Queue when you click on "System events monitor" ("Site utilities -> Internal:" fieldset)

If not or if you encountered some troubles when trying access to them, maybe you have had some troubles during the installation of the plugin.

If there is no problem and you see the service in the "Configuration of predefined services", you can create the service in your project and copy each field from the predefined service.

Anyway, if git service is available in the "Configuration of predefined services" and you cannot see it in a new project administration, you can try to uninstall the plugin and install it again. Another thing that works sometimes is to update Tuleap.